# converting a pine script strategy to study

Tags: alert, pine-script, algorithmic-trading

I want to convert a TradingView pine script "Price Channel Strategy" to a study. can someone please help?

The code is as given below:

```
//@version=4
strategy("ChannelBreakOutStrategy", overlay=true)

length = input(title="Length", type=input.integer, minval=1, maxval=1000, defval=5)

upBound = highest(high, length)
downBound = lowest(low, length)

if (not na(close[length]))
    strategy.entry("ChBrkLE", strategy.long, stop=upBound + syminfo.mintick, comment="ChBrkLE")
    strategy.entry("ChBrkSE", strategy.short, stop=downBound - syminfo.mintick, comment="ChBrkSE")
strategy.exit("long_tsl", "ChBrkLE", trail_points = 4000, trail_offset = 1500)
strategy.exit("short_tsl", "ChBrkSE", trail_points = 4000, trail_offset = 1500)
```

Answer (score 0):

Mainly, you have to change the word `strategy` to `study` at the top of your code.
You'll also have to remove the `strategy.entry/exit` calls since those aren't allowed in a `study`.
See here for some more information: https://marketscripters.com/pine-script-strategy-vs-study/